# How should I express the idea of a website having very few visitors?

Tags: single-word-requests

I just checked the Chinese Language & Usage site and found that there had been only one or two questions being asked per day. I need a word or an expression to describe a website like this. In particular, I'd like to fill in the blank in the following sentence.

> The **_** of the CLU site makes me want to join the sales team and help
>   promote the site.

The words I have thought of include *depression*, *unpopularity*, *inactivity*...None of them seems a good fit.

Comment: how about *neglect*?

Comment: @Jim Thanks for mentioning _neglect_. I wasn't aware of it. _neglect_ seems to place users at the center of the subject. I prefer a word that would describe the nature of the website.

Comment: @Jim For example, the depression of the US economy makes me want to start my own business.

Comment: The *underuse* of this valuable resource makes me...

Comment: *They stayed away in droves.*

Comment: *Lack of eyeballs*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Low traffic"

Not too judgmental but gets the message across.

See [Web Traffic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_traffic)

Answer (score 1):

**poor patronage**

[emphasis mine.]
[The Bridge](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&ved=0CEkQIDAF&url=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aonc3eyNad6UJ%3awww.eppcarl.org.au/bridge/the_bridge_2012_12.pdf%2b&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk&ei=LhVqUoShPM6prAfmnoCoCg&usg=AFQjCNH4VCewgkvCcZ7jbX2V1vFPUuSx8A&bvm=bv.55123115,d.bmk) Iss.13, Dec.2012:

> Since its inception the **website’s patronage** has grown and now receives several thousand unique visitors per month and it is a testament to …

So Won Jeong, *The Effects of Product Presentation on Consumer Experiences, Emotion, and Website Patronage Intention Towards an Apparel Website* ([GoogleBooks](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=0WJ5boAfB04C&dq=%22website%20patronage%22&source=gbs_navlinks_s)):

> The objectives of this study were to examine: (1) whether Pine and Gilmore's (1999) four experience realms (4Es) are affected by website features, (2) whether the 4Es affect consumer emotional components of pleasure and arousal, and (3) whether pleasure and arousal lead to enhanced **website patronage** intention.

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/patronage):

> *the direct train link was ending because of poor patronage*